# Why does the Python allow str to be multiplied with int?

Tags: python, types

Suppose we defined a function as follows:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b
```

Calling it by passing numbers works obviously:

```
In [5]: multiply(2,3)
Out[5]: 6
```

But this (surprisingly) works as well knowing that Python is a strongly-typed language:

```
In [6]: multiply('2', 3)
Out[6]: '222'
```

or this

```
In [7]: multiply(3, '2')
Out[7]: '222'
```

The implicit type conversion quite scares me. What was the rationale behind the `str` type design decision? In F#, on the other hand, it is not allowed:

```
- '3' * 2;;
  '3' * 2;;
  ------^
/Users/Pac/stdin(14,7): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not match the type 'char'
```

Comment: There's no type conversion going on. Instead multiplying a string with an integer is an old and well-known feature, that simply replicates the string (so no conversion). So e.g. `'foo' * 3` becomes `'foofoofoo'`.

Comment: My favorite use for this is writing out separators in command line scripts: `print '=' * 79`

Answer (score 5):

No type conversion is going on but the string type has a number of operations which provide useful shortcuts that are quite logical when you think about it:

- Multiply `*` = Duplicate so `'abcd ' * 4` **->** `'abcd abcd abcd abcd '`
- Add `+` = Concatenate so `'abcd' + 'efg'` **->** `'abcdefg'` **but** `'abcd' + 3` **->** `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

The tricks to find out what operations are available for any given type is, *other than reading the manual,* `dir(x)` and `help(x)` where x is an instance to the type, so:

```
dir('a')
__add__, __class__, __contains__, __delattr__, __doc__, __eq__, __format__, 
__ge__, __getattribute__, __getitem__, __getnewargs__, __getslice__, __gt__,
__hash__, __init__, __le__, __len__, __lt__, __mod__, __mul__, __ne__, __new__,
__reduce__, __reduce_ex__, __repr__, __rmod__, __rmul__, __setattr__,
__sizeof__, __str__, __subclasshook__, _formatter_field_name_split, _formatter_parser,
capitalize, center, count, decode, encode, endswith, expandtabs, find, format, index,
isalnum, isalpha, isdigit, islower, isspace, istitle, isupper, join, ljust,
lower, lstrip, partition, replace, rfind, rindex, rjust, rpartition, rsplit, rstrip,
split, splitlines, startswith, strip, swapcase, title, translate, upper, zfill
```

As you can see this contains the operators `__add__` and `__mul__` for add and multiply.

Answer (score 3):

It's a feature of Python, notice that `3 * '2'` is not `6`. It's multiplying the contents of the string 3 times.

Another (useful) example:

```
>>> [2] * 3
[2, 2, 2]
```

> knowing that Python is a strongly-typed language:

Yes it's strongly typed, so for example `'3' + 2` does not work as that wouldn't make any sense. However the multiplication across different types is useful - unfortunately it is an inconsistency where if you see one operator fail due to strong-typing, you would expect this from others as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @[Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) noted, this is not an example of type casting. Instead, it is more or less consistent with the standard notation used to describe finite sequences of symbols. If you refer to a textbook on finite automata and the like, [image: x^i] for an integer *i* indicates concatenation of string *x*  *i* times. Compare also `x + y` commonly used to concatenate strings `x` and `y` (also in Python). In that notation, `x + x == 2 * x`